# is boost::detail::atomic_count thread safe?

Tags: c++, boost, thread-safety, int, atomic

I'm incrementing/decrementing boost::detail::atomic_count in multiple threads.
Wonder if this practice is ok or if I need a lock around it(then I could just use regular int variable)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire purpose of an atomic variable is to be lock-free* and thread-safe.

So yes, it's perfectly safe; no, you don't need a lock.

---

*That is, the "lock" is done at hardware level. Are you using something without understanding it first? :)